# Do I have to install jxmpp library separatly when using smack library. Intellij not recognizing some keywords

Tags: java, intellij-idea, xmpp, smack, web-development-server

I'm building a client to connect to openfire server using smack(a xmpp library)
but I'm facing many problems.[image: I pressed ctrl and clicked configBuilder and This error appeared]
This is the main code[image: Main code]

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated. I also want to ask do I have to ask jxmpp library separatly? How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are missing this library from Maven Repository which is : `org.jxmpp:jxmpp-jid:1.0.3`

follow these steps to download the missing library in intellij

1. click File -> Project Structure
2. click on `libraries` tab on the left
3. you will see a `+` sign in the window shown, click on it
4. you will see a drop down menu , choose `from Maven...`
5. in the search bar type `org.jxmpp` and hit search icon
6. give it a minute till end searching then hit the drop down and choose the library to import which is `org.jxmpp:jxmpp-jid:1.0.3` , it will ask you where to download the `jar` file , choose the location and hit import , that should solve the problem of missing libraries

Comment: I have tried your method but I am not finding the exact version